# how to access variable when one controller is inside another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Could you please tell me How to access variable when one controller is inside another ..Actually Could you please tell me Can sub controller access above **variable** of super controller .

Let Example :

http://plnkr.co/edit/sKG9nN67P9McXYGXXIzZ?p=preview

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="firstCont">
        <div ng-controller="secondCont">
            <input type="text" ng-model="message">
            <h1>{{message}}</h1
        </div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data">
        <h1>{{data}}</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Second Controller is inside the firstcontroller. When I change in input field it reflect on header.

But If I do some change in my code .Try to access above controller variable in sub controller can we do that ?But not able to do ? how it will be achieve

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="firstCont">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data">
    <h1>{{data}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="secondCont">
        <input type="text" ng-model="message">
        <h1>{{data}}</h1
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you please tell the access modifier rules ?

**Edit**

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="firstCont">
   <input type="text" ng-model="data.data">
   <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>

   <div ng-controller="secondCont">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
   <h1>{{data.data}}</h1
     </div>

   </div>


   </div>
```

Comment: you can make `services` or `factory` in order to access variable value from one controller to other

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava we cannot access without factory ot service ? Like in java we access public or static variable of super class

Comment: you can if children `ctrl` want to access parent scope ,here is blog for it https://rclayton.silvrback.com/parent-child-controller-communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variables are strings then the child controller will create a new instance of the variable and not look to the parent scope. If you make your variable an object, the child controller will look to the parent controller for the value.  So have create a `data` variable in your parent controller and give it a `data.message` property. Then in the child controller you can access it with `ng-scope="data.message`.

Check out this link for more info:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ngRepeat

Here is your code edited:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="firstCont">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.data">
        <h1>{{data.data}}</h1>
        <div ng-controller="secondCont">
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
            <h1>{{data.data}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please modified my code so that better understand

Comment: In your controller, change it to `ng-model=data.data` and `{{data.data}}`. In your child controller change it to `ng-model=data.message` and `{{data.data}}`.

Comment: thanks I understand...Please check my edit ..can we access sub controller to super controller

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean exactly. If you have a follow up question I would recommend asking it as a separate question now that you have the code working the way you want. You'll get better quality answers that way.